# Having problems with Firebase access rules

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is mostly me playing with various cloud storage mechanisms, so I came with some test code.  In this one, I wanted to have users and group them into households.  The data structures I have in Firestore are:

```
Users/{user}/
    name (string)
    email (string)
    admin (bool)

Households/{household}/
    name (string)
    users (array of string)
```

The identifier for `{user}` is the user ID from the `User` api (I'm using Swift for my code); the identifier for `{household}` is a UUID.

The rules I have for the database are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{uid} {
            allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
            allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null && (request.auth.uid == uid || isAdmin());
      allow delete: if isAdmin();
    }
    match /Households/{household} {
            allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
            allow read, write: if hasAccess(household);
    }
    function hasAccess(household) {
        let id = (request.auth != null) ? string(request.auth.uid) : "";
      let users = id == "" ? [] : get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Households/$(household)).data.users;
        return id != null && ((id in users) || isAdmin());
      }
      function isAdmin() {
            let id = request.auth.uid;
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(id)).data.admin == true;
        }
  }
}
```

The Playground works with my UID; however, my *code* does not -- it gets an access denied error.  (If I set my UID to have `admin` set to true, it works, so I know *that* part of the rules is working.)

A different problem on stackoverflow I found yesterday ([63621376](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621376/firestore-rule-succeeds-in-playground-and-client-but-returns-permissions-denied)) showed the same problem, and it was fixed by converting a value to a string, which you can see I try there.

I have been unable to get the CLI emulator working, primarily because I use Macs, and I haven't been able to get the 1.8 version of Java installed in a way that it can work with.

ETA the client code:

```
        let ref = self.dbHouseholds!
        ref
            .whereField("users", arrayContains: self.user?.id ?? "")
            .getDocuments { snapshots, err in
                print("snapshots = \(snapshots), err = \(err)")
        }
```

It also fails if I don't have the `.whereField` query.  The errors are

```
snapshots = nil, err = Optional(Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that isn't working the way you expect.  Rules aren't very meaningful outside the context of specific queries to allow or reject.

Comment: Done; I'll add that for the playground query, I did authenticated, used my UID (that I printed out elsewhere in my test program), for a specific "household", whereas that one is trying to read through them all, and I can't do that in the playground (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is denying your query because [Firebase security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Please be sure to read and understand that documentation thoroughly.

The playground allows you to perform a request for a single document, but what you're showing here is a collection query, which you can't simulate in the console.  When you perform a collection query, the rules will reject any query where there is any possible document that might not allow access.  Rules will not scan every single document to pick out the ones that match - that does not scale at all.

Your function `hasAccess` depends on the value of a variable "household" containing an individual document ID being accessed.  Since you are querying for many documents, you can't use that variable to check each document.

If you want to write a rule that requires that users can only query documents that have their UID in the users field, you'll have to write that condition like this instead:

```
request.auth.uid in resource.data.users
```

This will enforce the where clause in your query.

Comment: So instead of the get, just have the `request.auth.uid in resource.data.users`?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to also say “That’s *it*?!” :). I will attempt when I get back to a laptop, instead of the iPad that wouldn’t let me type a multi-line response :).

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH.  That did the trick, and now it properly works.  I had a typo which confused me for way too long. My head hurts so much less now, thank you!

Comment: Great!  On Stack Overflow it's customary to upvote and accept answers as correct that were helpful using the buttons to the left of the answer.

Comment: I did the upvote thing, didn't know about the check before. My upvote was recorded but won't show it because I'm a newbie. :)